# c# recursion check if even

Tags: c#, if-statement, recursion

I need help understanding this. I really don't understand this piece of code and could someone here explain exactly what happens?

So this is the code:

```
static bool IsEven(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return true;

    if (IsEven(n - 1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then I do this:

`Console.WriteLine(IsEven(10));`

How does it actually work? If I enter in number 10, it prints out true. If I enter number 7, it prints out false. But I don't understand why it even works.

It checks if the number is 0, then it returns true. But I entered 10 (which clearly is not 0) and it still print out true. Then it checks number -1.

So that would be 10-1, which is 9. But how does it know that 9 is NOT even? (it returns false).

I don't understand this code, but it works. I am so confused honestly.

Comment: `So that would be 10-1, which is 9. But how does it know that 9 is NOT even? (it returns false).`  Keep following that same line of thought 9 more times.

Comment: But if it keeps subtracting 1 all the time. Eventually, every number will be 0?

Comment: Yes, it will.  So now you know how it works.

Comment: Yes, every non-negative integer will eventually reach 0.  This is one definition of the integers.

Comment: But the condition will alternate. Take some small numbers and run it on the paper.

Comment: Or if you want the computer to do that trace for you, stick in some useful print statements.

Comment: But if every number will end up being 0, then will it not return true for all numbers? I don't understand it. It's probably so easy for you guys to understand it, but I'm completely new to this way of thinking and I don't see how it would work. Even if I choose number 1000 or 37 or 99, they will all end up with 0. So it will eventually be "true" for all??

Comment: No, the function returns the *opposite* of what the (n-1) call returns.  0 is even, 1 is odd, 2 is even, 3 is odd, ...

Comment: @jeroenwiskas: `return true;` doesn't make `Console.WriteLine(IsEven(7))` print true, it makes the `IsEven(n-1)` return true, when `n-1` was zero.  The program continues with the `if`.  The line `if (IsEven(n-1))` doesn't forget the value of `n` and start thinking about `n-1` instead... it makes note of what it is doing, goes and figures out `IsEven(n-1)`, **then comes back to this spot in the program** and follows the `if`.

Comment: Recursion is so confusing to me. I could understand it if it subtracted 2 each time. But if it's -1, then it will just all become 0 at the end. I've honestly looked at this code for a good 20 minutes and still don't understand how it can work, hahaha

Comment: Have you tried already to run it on the paper for `1` ? For `2`? For `3`? That's should be enough to understand.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: His problem is the mental model for a function call expression... if you run on paper and stop with the first `return` you reach, you same way you would if you were studying iteration (loops), you will get the wrong result from paper as well.

Comment: Forget programming. Is it more clear `f(0)=true; f(n)=not(f(n-1))` ?

Comment: I'm too big of a dumbass to understand recursion. Hahahah, screw this!

Comment: The above is very easy to understand. `0` is even by definition. And every next number is the opposite of the previous one. And the code is doing almost the same.

Comment: Or you can use a debugger and step the code line by line starting by small number. It should be very obvious which lines are executed in which order and how variables are modified during program execution.

Comment: one more simple version, everything ends up at 0 for sure. But it took either an even or odd number of steps to get there (coungint down by one) and the logic in the function alternates between returning true and false , so odd ones get false and even ones get true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk through it logically using a lower number like 3 so there are not as many recursions to think about.

The first time we call `IsEven(3);` it does this:

```
if (3 == 0) return true;
```

Well 3 does not equal 0 so it continues with this:

```
if (IsEven(3 - 1))
```

Which is the same as:

```
if (IsEven(2))
```

So now we're in the next call to `IsEven`. The first check is `2 == 0` which of course it is not, so it continues with `IsEven(2 - 1)`.

Now we're in the third call to `IsEven` with `IsEven(1)`. Well again `1 == 0` is not true so it continues with `IsEven(1 - 1)`.

Now we're in the final (fourth) call to `IsEven` with `IsEven(0)`. Well now `0 == 0` is true so we return `true` back to the third call.

So now back in the third call `IsEven(1 - 1)` is `true` so it performs the action in the first bracket which is to return `false`.

Back in the second call `IsEven(2 - 1)` is now `false` so it takes the action in the second bracket which is return `true`.

Back in the first call `IsEven(3 - 1)` is true so it takes the action in the first bracket which is to return `false` indicatining that 3 is  indeed not even.

It's like integer inception.

Of course a real example would probably use the modulo `%` operator like this.

```
public static bool IsEven(int number)
{
    return number % 2 == 0; 
}
```

Comment: Well since yours is easier to understand (imho) than my wall of text have an upvote to even it out ;-)

Comment: I've read your reply like 10 times now and I'm starting to understand this integer inception that is going on. Still a bit confusing. But I think I get it. Going to make some tests and try it with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this:

```
IsEven(3)
|   IsEven(2)
|   |   IsEven(1)
|   |   |   IsEven(0)
|   |   |   Return True
|   |   Return False
|   Return True
Return False
```

It's always going to eventually get to 0 if the input was non-negative and start going back up the chain. `IsEven(1)` above means that `IsEven(2)` and `IsEven(3)` is still being executed. Those method calls have not ended yet.

What the `IsEven(n)` method is doing is returning the opposite of the lower number. Passing in `4` means it has to check if `3` is even. Since it isn't, it will return true for `4`.

As others have mentioned, I would suggest writing it out, but I would also suggest a breakpoint and using the `Step-In` IDE command to go into the `IsEven` method so you can watch the parameter value change and follow the flow as it is happening. Or at least add in some `Console.WriteLine` for you watch.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand it starting with mathematics. `0` is even by a definition. We know that each addition of `1` will flip the "eveness" of the number. So we can write the reursive rule as follows:

```
Base case: IsEven(0) = true
Induction: IsEven(n) = NOT( IsEven(n-1) ) ; for n > 0
```

So we can easily code it:

```
static bool IsEven(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return true;
    return (!IsEven(n - 1));
}
```

So far so good. But note, the `(!A)` can be rewritten instead as this awkward condition:

```
if (A)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

You can convince yourself by substituting `A` with `true` or `false`.

Now we just substitute `A` with `IsEven(n-1)` and paste it to the above code and get the original

```
static bool IsEven(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return true;

    if (IsEven(n - 1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```